# enum conformance to RawRepresentable

Tags: swift

In the Swift book, the example for enums works fine

```
enum CompassPoint: String {
    case north, south, east, west
}

var northCom = CompassPoint.north
print (northCom)
```

However I want to use a failable initializer so made an example of this

```
enum WeekDay: String {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
    init?(rawValue: Int){
        switch rawValue {
        case 0 : self = .monday
        case 1 : self = .tuesday
        case 2 : self = .wednesday
        case 3 : self = .thursday
        case 4 : self = .friday
        default : return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And get an error that Weekday does not conform to RawRepresentable - although I feel that conformance should be synthesized by the compiler so do not understand why this does not compile.

**What I've done** Created a similar working example (to see what the issue is), and still I want to conform to RawRepresentable using an enum with a failable initializer. I cannot find an example of this in the Swift book, in Stack Overflow questions or on the wider internet.

**What I've provided** Given a full example above, with the error as well as a working example of the behaviour I'm expecting.

**What is not helpful** Referencing the Swift book through a link or a comment is not helpful, as I've taken an example from there. I want to build on that example with a failable initializer. It is also not helpful to NOT use a enum, or a failable initializer. The question is about using a failable initalizer with a enum, and conforming to RawRepresentable. This is not homework, but those are the constraints of the question for my own learning and I'm interested in the outcome.

**The question** How can I use a failable initializer, with an enum as in the non-working example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently your definition of `init?(rawValue: Int)` prevents the compiler from inferring the `RawValue` type automatically. Adding a type alias helps:

```
enum WeekDay: String {
    typealias RawValue = String

    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday

    init?(rawValue: Int){
        switch rawValue {
        case 0 : self = .monday
        case 1 : self = .tuesday
        case 2 : self = .wednesday
        case 3 : self = .thursday
        case 4 : self = .friday
        default : return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively define your custom init function with a different parameter name:

```
enum WeekDay: String {

    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday

    init?(rawInt: Int){
        switch rawInt {
        case 0 : self = .monday
        case 1 : self = .tuesday
        case 2 : self = .wednesday
        case 3 : self = .thursday
        case 4 : self = .friday
        default : return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see now, can just call it index - saw this from use your loaf - https://useyourloaf.com/blog/enum-raw-values-and-failable-initializers/

Answer (score 4):

"although I feel that conformance should be synthesized by the compiler"

Yes, here your `rawValue` is of type String, not Int. Simply create your enum like:

```
enum WeekDay: String {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
}
```

And then create a `WeekDay` like this:

```
let monday: WeekDay? = WeekDay(rawValue: "monday")
let notADay: WeekDay? = WeekDay(rawValue: "foo")
```

Of course you can also add a custom init which takes an integer as argument:

```
enum WeekDay: String {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
    init?(integer: Int){
        switch integer {
        case 0 : self = .monday
        case 1 : self = .tuesday
        case 2 : self = .wednesday
        case 3 : self = .thursday
        case 4 : self = .friday
        default : return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And create your weekDay like:

```
let monday: WeekDay? = WeekDay(integer: 0)
let notADay: WeekDay? = WeekDay(integer: 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift 5 there is no error of having a second `init?(rawValue: Int)` in  addition to synthesized `init?(rawValue: String)`. But if you want to override that `RawRepresantable` implementation and have `rawValue` be `Int`, it is possible.

```
extension WeekDay : RawRepresentable {
    
    typealias RawValue = Int
    init?(rawValue: Int){
        switch rawValue {
        case 0 : self = .monday
        case 1 : self = .tuesday
        case 2 : self = .wednesday
        case 3 : self = .thursday
        case 4 : self = .friday
        default : return nil
        }
    }
    
    var rawValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .monday : return 0
        case .tuesday :  return 1
        case .wednesday : return 2
        case .thursday : return 3
        case .friday : return 4
        }
    }
}
print(WeekDay.init(rawValue: 2)) // Optional(WeekDay.wednesday)
print(WeekDay.RawValue.self) // Int
```